# Changing vertices from a polygon in Openlayers, gives multiple errors

Tags: firebug, openlayers, polygon, vertices

```
updatePolygon: function() {
    drawControls.modify.createVertices;
    var sides = 50;
    drawControls.regular.handler.sides = sides;
}
```

I have gotten this function from an OpenLayers example. It completely works, only firebug gives multiple errors hovering the points that are to be edited:

```
this.features["OpenLayers.Feature.Vector_" + (id - 1 + this.hitOverflow)] is undefined
http://freetrack.local/js/OpenLayers.js
Line 1310
```

Can someone help me solve this, because it doesn't look very neat.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

@Pepijn, I faced a challenge close to this one, had to change one point from the polygon, the following code worked for, hope it helps.

```
var ls = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString([a, b]);

    // calculate scale
    var distance = a.distanceTo(b);
    var scale = newSize / distance;

    ls.resize(scale, a);
    var newB = ls.getVertices()[1];
    console.debug( 'novo b : ' + newB );

    var ownerFeature = vectors.getFeatureById(owner)
    var points = ownerFeature.geometry.getVertices();

    for (var i=0;i<points.length-1;i++){
        if( points[i].x == b.x && points[i].y == b.y ){
            console.debug('found b');
            ownerFeature.geometry.addComponent(newB,i);
            ownerFeature.geometry.removeComponent(b);
            vectors.redraw();
            break;      
        }
    }
```